# Upload video to YouTube as unlisted

Tags: php, zend-framework, youtube

So, I am able to upload a video to YouTube (direct upload) using the PHP client library and set it to private, but is it possible to set it as unlisted?

Comment: I am asking exactly the same question, why is this "closed as not a real question"? babonk is asking if it is possibe to set the uploaded video as "unlisted". It's an acceptable question if you have any experience with uploading to youtube via PHP.

Comment: I don't know man. 5 people thought it was a bad question.

Comment: This was a pretty legit question, here's the answer: http://groups.google.com/group/youtube-api-gdata/browse_thread/thread/c5b08f33f80359e0/4553feb293104c0b

Comment: I came here from Googling 'zend upload unlisted video'. I also concur that this is a legitimate question.

Comment: Yea this should not have been closed

Comment: Good question, kinda look for the same :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use this code as a child of the XML element of the request:

```
<yt:accessControl action="list" permission="denied"/>
```

If you can't add it manually (usually using zend) you may use this code to add the corresponding zend entry:

```
//Creates an extension to Zend Framework
$element = new Zend_Gdata_App_Extension_Element('yt:accessControl', 'yt', 'http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007', ''); 

//Adds the corresponding XML child/attribute
$element->extensionAttributes = array(array('namespaceUri' => '', 'name' => 'action', 'value' => 'list'), array('namespaceUri' => '', 'name' => 'permission', 'value' => 'denied')); 

//Adds this extension to you video entry where "$myVideo" is your video to be uploaded
$myVideo->extensionElements = array($element);
```

Hope this helps :D

Answer (score 0):

Do that.. with API ver 2 and ZEND GDATA.
If you look at the content of a $videoEntry you will note a 
$_extensionElements and $_extensionArributes.
So looking backwards from the extended class of VideoEntry
you will found the abstract class Zend_Gdata_App_Base
and it has a function setExtensionElements(array).
So only do what others say to create the accesControlElement 
and pass it to that function.. 
And IT WORKS.

```
$videoEntry = $yt->getFullVideoEntry($id);

if ($videoEntry->getEditLink() !== null) {

    echo "<b>Video is editable by current user</b><br />";

    $putUrl = $videoEntry->getEditLink()->getHref();

    //set video to unlisted
    $accessControlElement = new Zend_Gdata_App_Extension_Element(
        'yt:accessControl', 'yt', 'http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007', ''
    );
    $accessControlElement->extensionAttributes = array(
        array(
            'namespaceUri' => '',
            'name' => 'action',
            'value' => 'list'
        ),
        array(
            'namespaceUri' => '',
            'name' => 'permission',
            'value' => 'denied'
        ));

    // here is the hidden function 
    // it´s on a abstract class Zend/Gdata/App/Base/Base.php 
    // Where ZEND/Gdata/Youtube/VideoEntry.php extends

    $videoEntry->setExtensionElements(array($accessControlElement));

    $yt->updateEntry($videoEntry, $putUrl);

}else{

    echo "<b>EL Video no es editable por este usuario</b><br />";

}
```